# Mi "pizarra" de turtle no se cierra después de hacer el dibujo

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Estoy trabajando en un programa, en el que debo desplegar este mensaje y otros en la pizarra de python, usando turtle. Mi problema está en que, cuando quiero mostrar otro dibujo u otro mensaje, el dibujo anterior no se elimina, sino que dibujo sobre el mismo. ¿Qué puedo hacer?

Tengan piedad de un estudiante de primer semestre :)

Mi código:

```
from turtle import * 
def anunciono ():

    speed("slow")
    goto (0, 0)
    penup()
    bk(121*2)
    rt(90)
    bk(50*2)
    pendown()
    fillcolor("red")
    begin_fill()
    for i in range(8):
        fd(100*2)
        lt(45)
    end_fill()
    penup()
    goto (0, 0)
    pendown()
    write("No pertenece al grupo actual de vacunación", font=("Arial", 15, "bold"), align=("center"))
```

Answer (score 0):

la verdad es que no entiendo bien como estás implementando tu código, por lo general se importa de otra forma:

```
import turtle
```

después se declara las variables que inician turtle:

```
lapiz= turtle.Turtle() #el lapiz
ventana=turtle.Screen()#la ventana
```

en el caso de tu función hay que agregar el iniciador:

```
def anunciono():

    lapiz.speed("slow")
    lapiz.goto(0,0)
    lapiz.penup()
    lapiz.bk(121*2)
    lapiz.rt(90)
    lapiz.bk(50*2)
    lapiz.pendown()
    lapiz.fillcolor("red")
    lapiz.begin_fill()
    for i in range(8):
        lapiz.fd(100*2)
        lapiz.lt(45)
    lapiz.end_fill()
    lapiz.penup()
    lapiz.goto (0, 0)
    lapiz.pendown()
    lapiz.write("No pertenece al grupo actual de vacunación", font=("Arial", 15, 
"bold"), align=("center"))
```

y por último llamar a la función y la función que se encarga de mantener la ventana visible hasta que se desee cerrarla.

```
anunciono()
ventana.exitonclick()
```

Supongo que si entendí, eso mostrará tu código.

Comment: Muchas gracias!! No había pensado en hacer eso. Importé turtle así para no tener que asignarle una variable, pero creo que de la forma en que tu lo haces es más eficiente.